# anaconda/conda - install a specific package version

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to install the 'rope' package in my current active environment using conda. Currently, the following 'rope' versions are available:

```
(data_downloader)user@user-ThinkPad ~/code/data_downloader $ conda search rope
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
cached-property              1.2.0                    py27_0  defaults        
                             1.2.0                    py34_0  defaults        
                             1.2.0                    py35_0  defaults        
                             1.3.0                    py27_0  defaults        
                             1.3.0                    py34_0  defaults        
                             1.3.0                    py35_0  defaults        
rope                         0.9.4                    py26_0  defaults        
                             0.9.4                    py27_0  defaults        
                             0.9.4                    py33_0  defaults        
                             0.9.4                    py34_0  defaults        
                             0.9.4                    py26_1  defaults        
                             0.9.4                    py27_1  defaults        
                             0.9.4                    py33_1  defaults        
                             0.9.4                    py34_1  defaults        
                          .  0.9.4                    py35_1  defaults
```

I would like to install the following one:

```
                         1.3.0                    py35_0  defaults
```

I've tried all sorts of permutations of 'conda install' which I'm not going to list here because none of them are correct.

I am also not sure what the *py35_0* is (I'm assuming this is the version of the python against which the package was built?) and I also don't know what 'defaults' means?

Comment: did you try `conda install package=version`? e.g. `conda install matplotlib=1.4.3`

Comment: @CharlieParker -- Thanks that worked.  I wasn't able to gather that using equals in that fashion would work from reading the help text. -- The help text really made it seem like I would have to somehow correlate the revision number to a version number and specify it that way (with `--revision`).  Thanks again!

Comment: if you want at least a specific version don't forget the quotes `conda install -y networkx">=2.5"`

Comment: FYI the version `1.3.0` corresponds to the package `cached-property` (at the top, matching your query `rope`), while the version of `rope` available is just `0.9.4`. `defaults` is a channel name used for your search - you can search other channels using e.g. `-c conda-forge` (that's the largest and the most useful channel).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

There is no version `1.3.0` for `rope`. `1.3.0` refers to the package `cached-property`. The highest available version of `rope` is `0.9.4`.

You can install different versions with `conda install package=version`. But in this case there is only one version of `rope` so you don't need that.

The reason you see the `cached-property` in this listing is because it contains the string `"rope"`: "cached-p **rope** erty"

`py35_0` means that you need python version `3.5` for this specific version. If you only have `python3.4` and the package is only for version `3.5` you cannot install it with conda.

I am not quite sure on the `defaults` either. It should be an indication that this package is inside the default conda channel.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I'm starting with conda and totally missed that 'cached-property' is just another package.

Comment: @s5s The `defaults` does indicate that the package will be installed from the default package repository. The `pyXY` indicates that that particular package is available for Python X.Y, while the `_Z` indicates the "build number" which is incremented when the way that the package is created is changed, but the actual code in the package is unchanged.

Comment: Command to install specific package `conda install rope=0.9.4` [This is a link to Conda Documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html)

Comment: How can I choose python version? If I want to install with 1.3.0 version of package for python 3.5?

Comment: for people looking for an actual answer with executable code: `conda install <pkg>=<version>` e.g. `conda install matplotlib=1.4.3`

Comment: The answer by @jonathan-l below is a more general answer to the general title of the question and is not specific to the `rope` package...  https://stackoverflow.com/users/1667163/jonathan-l

Answer (score 276):

To install a specific package:

```
conda install <pkg>=<version>
```

eg:

```
conda install matplotlib=1.4.3
```

For more complex expressions, the relation can be quoted:

```
conda install 'matplotlib>=1.4.3'

# or

conda install "matplotlib>=1.4.3"
```

Comment: is there a way to say "at least version 2.5"? e.g. `conda install -y networkx=>2.5`?

Comment: this worked for me: `conda install -y networkx">=2.5"`

Comment: this didn't work for me: `conda install samtools>=1.14`

Comment: @ÖmerAn one must prevent shell from evaluating the `>` symbol: `conda install 'samtools>=1.14'`

Comment: Single quote does not work for me, only double (windows)

Answer (score 108):

If any of these characters: `' ', '>', '<', '|', '*'` are used, a single or double quotes must be used, e.g.:

```
conda install [-y] package">=version"
conda install [-y] package'>=low_version, <=high_version'
conda install [-y] "package>=low_version, <high_version"

conda install -y torchvision">=0.3.0"
conda install  openpyxl'>=2.4.10,<=2.6.0'
conda install "openpyxl>=2.4.10,<3.0.0"
```

where option `-y`, `--yes` means: "Do not ask for confirmation".

Here is a summary:

```
Format         Sample Specification     Results
Exact          qtconsole==4.5.1         4.5.1
Fuzzy          qtconsole=4.5            4.5.0, 4.5.1, ..., etc.
>=, >, <, <=  "qtconsole>=4.5"          4.5.0 or higher
               qtconsole"<4.6"          less than 4.6.0

OR            "qtconsole=4.5.1|4.5.2"   4.5.1, 4.5.2
AND           "qtconsole>=4.3.1,<4.6"   4.3.1 or higher but less than 4.6.0
```

Portion of the above information credit to [Conda Cheat Sheet](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf)

Tested on `conda` 4.7.12.

Comment: The quotes don’t seem mandatory for `anaconda-project.yml`.

Comment: Now that makes perfect sense in a console (and the same goes for `pip`) : without quotes the smaller/larger-than characters will be interpreted as redirections.

Comment: This is the best answer, in terms of being most complete and providing a direct answer to the question.  This gets my up-vote !!

Comment: why are the quotes needed?

Comment: @CharlieParker, the quotes make characters like '>', '<', '|' or '*' get properly interpreted

Comment: This the best and most complete answer that I have found for the questions of bounding a package version to a specific range.  This should be the preferred answer.

Answer (score 0):

Conda seems to be spinning for a long time (+5min) in "Solving environment" if I use an exact version:

$ conda install nodejs=18.16.0

It ran much faster if I loosen up the version a bit:

$ conda create -yn node18 'nodejs>=18,<19'