# How to conda install a Python package with min and max version range?

Tags: python, conda

I need to know how to use Conda to install a Python package within a specific version range.    Specifically, I am using Spyder 4.2.1 and I want to use the `spyder-kernels` package to change to a Python interpreter in another Conda virtual environment.  When I do this I get an error message:

> Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 1.10.0 and < 1.11.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.
>
> You can install it by running in a system terminal:
>
> `conda install spyder‑kernels`

What I tried was: `conda install "spyder-kernels<1.11.0"` but it threw an error message.

I found instructions for doing this with `pip` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip). However, I never use pip within Conda environments unless I want to dead-end my Conda environment.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.

`conda install "spyder-kernels>=1.10, <1.11.0"`

Then I found an excellent in-depth explanation within another StackOverflow answer that has the specific syntax.

[Syntax to conda install a Python package within a specified range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411942/anaconda-conda-install-a-specific-package-version/58630489#58630489)