# Installing conda-forge package

Tags: python, anaconda, julia, conda

I want to use an older version of Julia package in my conda env. I downloaded a tar package corresponding to the required version from the website https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/julia/files but not really sure how to install this in my conda environment.
Help please!

I tried  `conda install julia=1.7.3` but no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [anaconda/conda - install a specific package version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411942/anaconda-conda-install-a-specific-package-version)

Comment: I tried conda install julia=1.7.3 but it failed

Comment: Did you include the channel specification? `conda install -c conda-forge julia=1.7.3`